# Clear button in multiselect widget

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

is there way to add clear button in slate multiselect widget?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Would adding a clear button widget next to your multiselect widget work?  (screenshot below)

[image: string selector and a clear button]

Comment: I have already added clear button next to multiselect. I was wondering if we can add button inside widget.